# 2x2 code tab layout in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I wanted to change the way my workspace worked a bit today.

The way I wanted to set it up is to create a two by two tab layout so I can view and group 4 sets of (code) files. However, once I create a 1x2 or 2x1, only other option was to expand the existing layout (2x1 -> 3x1 -> 4x1 -> 5x1, etc, and vice versa).

Is there a way to create a 2x2 (or any other code tab configuration) in Visual Studio 2017?

EDIT: Seriously? You need a $50 plugin to do something so basic? There is no other way?

Answer (score 1):

You may find my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension useful. It allows you to open code in multiple rows and, on a wide screen, additionally in multiple columns:

[image]

Comment: That's great, but that's $50 for something that should have been included from the get-go!